# meaning of "attached face"

Tags: meaning

Wuats the meaning of "attached face" in this context?

He reveals a bulbous nose and an attached face that looked as
though it had been pulverized by a meat grinder

Answer (score 2):

### Its the face that's attached to the bulbous nose

As opposed to another face that isn't connected to the "bulbous nose".

Semantically, it's completely equivalent to "He reveals a bulbous nose and a face that looked as though it had been pulverized by a meat grinder." Evocatively, it creates a different emotional effect. Like the nose may, without warning, start an independent existence.

Comment: And specifically the effect is created by inverting the expression. We would normally say a nose is attached to a face, not the other way around. By introducing the nose first and then describing the face, it surprises us.